# How do I add more to JNI interface

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface

I followed a tutorial and built a JNI interface in Android studio. But I don't know how to add more to it by calling other functions in my C library. I am not even sure if I can see my library yet; I figure if I call one of the functions I would know. So my question is I do not understand the file in my JNI folder. I see it is written in C. Why is the #include different from the usual C includes I have seen which is something like #include  or I believe you can also say #include "foo.c" also? Why are there _'s in the package names? How do I call a function in one of my libraries two levels below the JNI folder? I read the JNI specification and still don't understand how JNIenv works.

For example, just to test this, I tried adding random.c to my file. It is located two levels below my JNI folder; ndk-builder says there is no such file. So I think I need to work on my Andorid.mk and make sure the build environment has visibility to random.c. Is that true? Can I somehow specify the fully qualified path to random.c?

```
#include "com_example_sansari_ndktest_MainActivity.h"
#include <random.c>

 JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL  
 Java_com_example_sansari_ndktest_MainActivity_HelloJNI
   (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
 (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"Hi From Sean");
}
```

@JP; Thanks. So I should be able to say something like the following in the above file:

(*env)->random();

And be able to receive an integer in my main activity? random() declares a static integer, modifies it, and returns it.

@JP. Thanks. so I can say 
random(); in my C file, and the value would show up in my MainActivity. Well that is good news; thanks. Now i gota figure out how to fix my Andorid.mk.

@JP. Thanks. i took it out. I really appreciate all your help.

Comment: I don't see anything different about these `#include` statements. There are underbars in the package names because they can't be dots as they are in Java.

Comment: `env->` is for calling JNI functions. You call your own directly.

Comment: Why would you `#include` a .c file? Include the corresponding header file instead, and link against the object file or library that contains its implementation.

Comment: Your edit says a lot of things that @Michael didn't say. .h files define interfaces; .c files provide implementations.